# No Adobe Program Installs on MacBook Pro Retina with El Capitan

Tags: macos, adobe

I am having this very strange problem with Adobe programs.

I reinstalled OSX on my macbook and I tried to install adobe programs however I keep getting the error in the screen shot. I have researching and nothing seems to fix it

Would anyone be able to help?

[image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot or quote from the **error summary**

Comment: @TheBro21 - Just now while trying to reinstall i get the error "A12E1"

Comment: A12E1 means download error. Could this be of any help? https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1045283

Comment: I have also used Creative cloud to download and a manual download of different programs. And I get the same problem. Apparently my drive is case sensitive? I'm not sure what that means

Comment: Case sensitive means that capitals make a difference. In non case sensitive devices, **Example** is the same as **example** or **eXaMpLe**